# nullReferenceExceptionUnhandled error on existing elements parsing XML using XDocument

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml, nullreferenceexception

Tried a 100 variations of parsing this xml I continually get at this point I though I better make a post before I start breaking things(like my monitor)

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=
  StackTrace:
       at Dashboard.Global.geocoder(Object o) in :line 60
       at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
       at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
       at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
       at System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback()
  InnerException:
```

The XML is very simple from FCC.gov

```
<Response xmlns="http://data.fcc.gov/api" status="OK" executionTime="91">
  <Block FIPS="181770103002004"/>
  <County FIPS="18177" name="Wayne"/>
  <State FIPS="18" code="IN" name="Indiana"/>
</Response>
```

My code has morphed quite a bit

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
XNamespace ns = xdoc.Root.Attribute("xmlns").ToString();
var results = xdoc.Element(ns + "Response").Element(ns + "Block").Attribute("FIPS"); //null ref

if (xdoc != null)
{
    var FIPS_State_Code = results.Value.Substring(0,1); //null ref
    var FIPS_County_Code = xdoc.Element("response"); //nullref
    var Census_Tract = xdoc.Element("response").Element("Block").Attribute("FIPS").Value; //null ref
    var Census_Block_Group = xdoc.Element("response").Element("Block"); //null ref
```

Answered by tomolak final product (if your actually pull census blocks):

```
 var xdoc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
                        XNamespace fcc = "http://data.fcc.gov/api";
                        var results = xdoc.Element(fcc + "Response").Element(fcc + "Block").Attribute("FIPS").Value.ToString();
                        if (xdoc != null)
                        {

                            var FIPS_State_Code = results.Substring(0,2);
                            var FIPS_County_Code = results.Substring(2, 3);
                            var Census_Tract = results.Substring(5, 6);
                            var Census_Block_Group = results.Substring(11, 4);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to pull the namespace URI from the input XML, you are supposed to actually put it into your program.

This works just fine:

```
XNamespace fcc = "http://data.fcc.gov/api";
var response = xdoc.Element(fcc + "Response");
var block = response.Element(fcc + "Block");
var country = response.Element(fcc + "County");
var state = response.Element(fcc + "State");

var FIPS_Block_Code = block.Attribute("FIPS").Value;
var FIPS_County_Code = country.Attribute("FIPS").Value;
var FIPS_State_Code = state.Attribute("FIPS").Value;
```

Of course you must also use the namespace everywhere, default namespaces like the one in your input XML are inherited.

This won't work:

```
xdoc.Element("response").Element("Block"); //null ref error
```

This will:

```
xdoc.Element(fcc + "Response").Element(fcc + "Block");
```

(Also note the capital R, XML is of course case-sensitive.)

Comment: Note that a good way to avoid null reference exceptions in LINQ to XML is to do an explicit conversion to `string` - i.e., `var FIPS_Block_Code = (string)block.Attribute("FIPS");` - if the attribute is not found it will return null.  Not a likely scenario in this case, but it's a good best practice, especially when you can't count on elements/attributes being present all the time.

Comment: This works perfectly ! I knew it had to be the namespace but I just couldnt get it right

Comment: @William Don't forget to close the thread by marking the answer as accepted if the issue has been solved.

Comment: @WilliamDunn - Best way to thank a person for providing his valuable time in solving your issue is by up-voting \accepting the answer. Check how you can do so here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work